# NodeJS - JSON Source Data File to Different Schema

Tags: node.js, json, schema

Need to transform a source JSON data file into a Different JSON schema format.  There are several hundred fields, so I was hoping to be able to template a Mapping of Source field to Target.  Any ideas?

**Source Sample:**

```
[  {
     orderNumber: 123,
     orderItemStatusTypeId: "OPEN",
     showInCatalog: TRUE
     usedOrderTicketNumber: "A232PQ"
   },
   ...
 ]
```

**Target Schema:**

```
Orders:
    type: array,
    items:
        Order: 
            title: order
            type: object
            properties:
            orderItemId:
                type: integer
                description: >-  
                    Source field is - `orderNumber`
                format: int64
            statusTypeId:
                type: string
                description: >-
                Source field is - `orderItemStatusTypeId`
            isShowInCatalog:
                type: boolean
                description: >-
                Source field is - `showInCatalog`
            ticketNumber:
                type: string
                description: >-
                Source field is - `usedOrderTicketNumber`
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using module 'flat'.  One thing for all to be aware, works fine for ES6 node apps running > 10.  However need to do extensive data validation, not that you already wouldn't, against data input when running against trireme.